# Psychopy gives the ffmpeg error and does not play the videos

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, psychopy

I want to create an experiment with Psychopy in which I will present randomly video that participant will have to evaluate.

I have created a routine with my MovieStim and my Rating response and a Loop with my conditions file (in which are my video files videoname.wmv). 
All my videos are in the same folder as my experiment.

I have specified the MovieStim with a variable refering to my Loop's column ($Stimulus).

But when I run the experiment I have this message.

```
Running: E:\Thèse ESPRIT\Approach_Aversion\Experience_AA\Approach_Aversion_lastrun.py 
pyo version 0.8.0 (uses single precision)
WARNING:root:Warning: could not find imageio's ffmpeg executable:
[Error 5] Accès refus: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PsychoPy2\\lib\\site-packages\\imageio\\resources\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.win32.exe'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Thèse ESPRIT\Approach_Aversion\Experience_AA\Approach_Aversion_lastrun.py", line 105, in <module>
    depth=0.0,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.84.2-py2.7.egg\psychopy\contrib\lazy_import.py", line 120, in __call__
    return obj(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.84.2-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\movie3.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.loadMovie(self.filename)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\psychopy-1.84.2-py2.7.egg\psychopy\visual\movie3.py", line 170, in loadMovie
    self._mov = VideoFileClip(filename, audio=(1 - self.noAudio))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 55, in __init__
    reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 32, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 237, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spécifié est introuvable
```

It seems to be something wrong with the ffmpeg executable but I don't understand what.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you very much fo advance !

Have a nice day.

Ivane

Comment: This person seems to have had a similar error and found a solution at the psychopy discourse site. Might want to read that. https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/video-crashes-differently-with-all-three-backends/1096 Bonne Chance.

Comment: Merci :) I've tried something like in the PsychoPy Discourse topic ! It seems to be good ! Thank you !